# Is it possible to Raze the 2nd capital?

Tags: civilization-5

I've annexed the American capital not knowing he had another city. I have no intrest in the 2nd one so I'd like to raze it, however it became his new capital, does the same "no razing capital" rule apply?

Comment: No, you can raze their second capital.

Comment: @NathanMerrill, don't answer in comments. If you have an answer, make a real answer for it and you'll gain rep.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, you can raze a civlization's "second" capitol, i.e. the city that the capitol is moved to once you capture their original capitol. You can't raze a civilization's *original* capitol, because a domination victory means "owning all civlizations' original capitols."

To find out whether a city is an original capitol, go to the Victory Progress screen. (It's one of the options when you click on the scroll icon near the upper-right corner.) In the Domination section, you can mouseover each civilization's symbol, and the title-text will tell you what that civilization's original capitol is, and who the current owner is. (Alternatively, you can simply memorize the name of each civilization's capitol city; it's always the same, unless you've been renaming cities. So Germany's capitol is *always* Berlin.)

Answer (score 1):

No. The "no razing the capital" rule exists for game balance. It makes it so that a nation can't be completely locked out of a domination victory because their original capital was razed. Their new capital has no meaning for domination victory conditions, so it can be raised as usual.

Comment: So the answer is yes? The OP is asking about razing the second capitol, not the original one.

Comment: The answer to the title is yes, the answer to the question below the title is no. Because the two questions are opposites.